# Discussion questions

Tags: discussion, support, questions, opinion-based

As some questions do not have an objective answer and one may want to know other people's thoughts on the subject, it may make sense to have questions which purpose is not to get a definitive answer to asker mark as the accepted one, but to poll opinions.

I, myself have asked one: [Fill CV like document](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98102/fill-cv-like-document), which in the comments was recognized as 'a very good topic for discussion'.

People purposed to make a discussion on the chat, but I quite disagree, given the chat is a thing for that time instant and future visitors will not get to there.

I purpose that such questions get the [discussion](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag instead of being put on hold.
Are you with me?

Comment: I'm afraid that would not be such a good idea, as all SE sites are about factually *questions* and *answers*  (although in other sites like here, where answers are more subjective, there are still guidelines for [good subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) questions and answers). Discussion is more for chat, and at *some small* degree comments. Also, asking here on Meta is sometimes the place for those questions.

Comment: Sometimes people say "This is a very good topic for discussion, but..." Just to soften the blow of the but and do not really mean the first part.  I am of the opinion that was the intent of the first comment on your question.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings; My opinion is there is **good discussions** which is productive and leads to conclusions; and **bad discsussion**, which is completely sterile, as it does not lead to anywhere, generates noise and should be avoided.

Comment: @sergiol - Maybe... but there are no "Good Discussions" to be had on the main site.  Those belong on meta or chat.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings: I argued on my post why chat was not a good idea.

Comment: @sergiol - Well those are the options here.  If you dont like those choices then this is probably not the place for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking to diverge from a core tenet of the SE Philosophy on the Question and Answer Site.

Answer (score 10):

> Are you with me?

### No.

[Stack Exchange is not a forum.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums) This is a Q&A site built around the concept of asking and answering questions and judging both. A discussion cannot be judged and is simply not supported by the site framework.

In [the words of Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75035/260382) (co-founder of the site for those not in the know):

> If this is really what you want, you need to do it on another engine. Ours simply cannot support these kinds of frivolous, pure entertainment based content.

The discussion tag is [blacklisted on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128287/how-come-discussion-tag-made-its-way-into-so) for a reason and the only reason that it's not blacklisted here is because we haven't had an issue with people actually using it.

It would in fact be a meta-tag [which are explicitly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) on the main sites. Our [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) is exceptionally clear on this.

Comment: If you want to discuss about more ethereal questions you are welcomed to ask in in out [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) ... you will most likely "poll" quite interesting opinions.